# Timeseries with Spark/Cassandra - How to find timestamps when values satisfy a condition?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, time-series

I have timeseries stored in a Cassandra table, coming from several sensors. Here is the schema I use for storing data :

```
CREATE TABLE data_sensors (
    sensor_id int,
    time timestamp,
    value float,
    PRIMARY KEY ((sensor_id), time)
);
```

Values can be temperature or pressure for instance, depending on the sensor from which it is coming from.

My objective is to be able to find basic statistics (min, max, avg, std) on pressure, but only when temperature is higher than a certain value.
Here is a schema of the whole process I'd like to get.
[image: schema of the process described before]

I think it could be better if I changed the Cassandra model, at least for temperature data, to be able to filter on value. Is there another way, after importing data into a Spark RDD, to avoid altering the Cassandra table?

Then, once filtering on temperature is done, how to get the sequence of timestamps I have to use to filter pressure data? Please note that I don't have necessarily the same timestamps for temperature and pressure, that is why I think I need to have periods of time instead of a list of precise timestamps.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a Cassandra-specific answer, but maybe you want to look at time series databases that provide SQL layer on top of NoSQL stores with support for JOINs and aggregations.

Here's an example of an [ATSD](https://github.com/axibase/atsd-docs/tree/master/sql#period) SQL syntax that supports period aggregations and joins.

```
SELECT t1.entity, t1.datetime, min(t1.value), max(t1.value), avg(t2.value)
  FROM mpstat.cpu_busy t1
  JOIN meminfo.memfree t2 
 WHERE t1.datetime >= '2016-09-20T15:00:00Z' AND t1.datetime < '2016-09-20T15:15:00Z'
  GROUP BY entity, t1.PERIOD(1 MINUTE)
  HAVING max(t1.value) > 30
```

The query joins two metrics, filters out 1-minute rows where first metric was below the threshold and then returns a bunch of statistics for the second series.

If the two series are unevenly spaced, you can regularize the array using [linear interpolation](https://github.com/axibase/atsd-docs/tree/master/api/sql#regularization).

Disclosure: I work for Axibase that develops ATSD.